# Why react native is generating "._" files ? Eg: ._Home.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I never faced this issue in other React native projects but in this one, I'm
getting these extra files. How to remove these and why they are generating?

[image]

Comment: Are you using MacOS? If so, does this answer your question? [Why are dot underscore files created and how can I avoid them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them)

Comment: That's great. Thank you. It answered my question.
 I was searching for the question in the wrong way.